# How to allow Facebook login simultaneously from both development on localhost and hosted production domain?

Tags: facebook

I am developing an app using Facebook login. When set to "status: development" on developers.facebook.com, I can use login for the app locally on localhost:3000. However, when I try to access the app from a hosted domain, Facebook login will complain that the app is in development mode. When I enable production mode on developers.facebook.com (make app public), I can then use login on the hosted domain, but I lose the ability to access the app locally on localhost:3000. Facebook complains for localhost:

> Facebook has detected `<MyApp>` isn't using a secure connection to
>   transfer information

How can I use FB login both while developing locally and published to the public? Right now I have to switch back and forth from `Status: Development` to `Status: Live`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a *test app* version of your app, and use that for development.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

> Similar to Test Users, Test Apps let you quickly create Facebook App IDs for use during the development, testing, staging or QA phases of the app development lifecycle.